# BCM94352z bluetooth not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth, broadcom

I recently replaced my wireless card with BCM94352z. The card working perfectly on Windows 10 and Hackintosh. And the 2.4GHz & 5GHz wifi is working well on Ubuntu 16.04 after installing Broadcom firmware.

Once I enter the bluetooth panel, it can show the findable device list correctly, but cannot connect to any of them.

---

I'm a newbie and I don't know what info should I attach here, please comment and I could update my question in time.

---

***Update:***

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
   Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
   Kernel driver in use: wl
   Kernel modules: bcma, wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f3:21d5 Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216f Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6713 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: You need firmware for this BT adapter.

Comment: You might just try this first: https://github.com/hg8/bluetooth-firmware-XPS13-9343